# using filters cause error in admin-on-resst

Tags: admin-on-rest

this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  List,
  Datagrid,
  TextField,
  DateField,
  Filter,
  TextInput,
} from 'admin-on-rest/lib/mui';

const fsFilter = props => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
);


export const fsList = props => (
  <List
    {...props}
    filters={<fsFilter />}
  >
  ...
```

I want to use filters in my list (search input) but I'm getting 2 warnings

```
Warning: Unknown props `showFilter`, `displayedFilters`, `filterValues`, `context` on <fsFilter> tag. Remove these props from the element...
```

and

```
Warning: Unknown props `hideFilter`, `setFilters` on <fsFilter> tag. Remove these props from the element...
```

what's wrong?

Comment: BTW admin-on-rest version is "^1.1.2"

Comment: What if you name your filter component starting with a capital, i.e. `fsFilter` => `FsFilter `?

Comment: thanks, that was the problem... but why??

Comment: That's JSX 101, see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized